# Chamar função PHP através de um botão em uma modal

Tags: php, ajax, modal, onclick

Estou exibindo a quantidade de arquivos de um diretório, dentro de uma **modal**, quero chamar uma função em `PHP` quando o usuário clicar no botão *"Apagar"*, tentei utilizar `onclick` , porém não funcionou.

**Meu código:**

```
 <!-- Meu modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="c_up_pa">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Arquivos sobrando...</h3>
          <hr>
          <p>
            <?php 
            foreach($files as $file){
            if(!in_array($file, $images)){

            echo "Cerca de <b>" .count($file). "</b> arquivo(s) que não estão no banco de dados <p>"; // Número total

            echo "Nomes dos arquivos: <b>" . $file . "</b><br>"; // Exibe os arquivos

           }}?>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" onclick="apagar_files()" class="btn btn-danger">Apagar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>

         <?php
           function apagar_files(){
           if (file_exists($file))
           unlink($file); }          
         ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> O que não estou conseguindo, é **chamar a função através de um botão** corretamente.

Como posso estar fazendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá. PHP é uma linguagem serve side, ou seja ela roda no servidor

HTML, CSS e JAVASCRIPT são processadas no client side, ou seja, roda no navegado do usuário.

Tendo isso em mente, o seu código não vai funcionar, já que você esta tentando rodar um processo Server Side no Client Side.

O que sugiro a você é realizar uma requisição AJAX em um arquivo.php e nesse arquivo você rodar o código da função.

Exemplo:

`$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btnDeletar').on('click', function(){
       $.ajax({ method: "POST",
       url: "deletar.php",
       success: function(data){
        alert('Arquivos Deletados');
       }
       });
   });
});`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, sou novo em programação! Vou fazer o teste.

Comment: Olá, o botão não faz nada aparenemente, ele está assim:   `<button type="submit" onclick="btnDeletar()">Apagar</button>` , eu coloquei o script abaixo já, e criei uma pagina chamada "*deletar.php*" e coloquei a ação, porém, não foi...

Comment: primeiro adicione a classe "bntDeletar"  ao seu botão de deletar, o type dele mude para button e tente novamente, caso ainda não funcione veja que erro da no console.

Comment: Aparece que "btnDeletar" não está definido

Comment: esqueci de mencionar, remova o onclick="btnDeletar()"

Comment: E coloco o que no `button` para referenciar ao script?

Comment: a classe btnDeletar